# How to better adjust placement of frametitle converted to marginpar in beamerarticle?

Tags: vertical-alignment, marginpar, beamerarticle

I'm using `beamer` and `beamerarticle` for my class notes. I would like to include `frametitles` as margin notes in `<article>` mode aligned with frame content but they are a little bit misplaced.

[image]

According to [LaTeX reference manual](ftp://ftp.tex.ac.uk/tex-archive/info/latex2e-help-texinfo/latex2e.html#Marginal-notes)

> The `\marginpar` command creates a note in the margin. The first line of
>   the note will have the same baseline as the line in the text where the
>   \marginpar occurs.

So, I think this misalignment is produced because there is no line (`frametitle` disappears) to be used as reference. Do you know how can it be improved?

Previous example was obtained with next code

```
%\documentclass{beamer}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\mode<article>{\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
       \marginpar{\insertframetitle\\%
       \scriptsize\insertframesubtitle}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Frame 1}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Frame 2}
\only<article>{\lipsum[3]}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{This is a long frame title}
\lipsum[3]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `\marginpar` you could use `\marginnote` from the [`marginnote`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/marginnote) package; this gives you the right position automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{beamerarticle}
\usepackage{marginnote}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\mode<article>{\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{%
  \marginnote{%
  \if\insertframetitle\empty\relax
  \else
    \insertframetitle\newline%
  \fi%
  \scriptsize\insertframesubtitle}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}{Subtitle}
\lipsum[1]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{}{Subtitle with no title}
\only<article>{\lipsum[3]}
\lipsum[2]
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{This is a long frame title}
\lipsum[3]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I also made change to the original definition, to produce a line break conditionally only if the title is provided.

Answer (score 3):

It seem that  margin notes are misplaced  `5pt`, so simply add `\vspace{5pt}` before `\insertframetitle`. However, it could better a relative space as `\vspace{.44\baselineskip}` since in this way could work also with other font sizes.

Comment: How did you find this `5pt` value? Is it somewhere documented? Did you find by trial and error?

Comment: @Ignasi, First I was thinking that margin notes are displaced just one half of `\baselineskip` (`6pt`) but for some reason it is really something less, so I adjusted this manually.